# Application has stopped unexpectedly error

Tags: android, sql

hi i am a beginner in android programming and I'm working with databases.  I was following a video and when I tried to run the app i kept getting this message "Application has stopped unexpectedly. please try again"
I don't know what I did wrong.
thanks

```
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.seenit/com.example.seenit.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at com.example.seenit.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-14 20:43:08.950: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  ... 11 more
```

Here's my MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
EditText movie, director, actors, genre;
Button bUpdate, bView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    movie = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMovie);
    director = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDirector);
    actors = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etActors);
    genre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etGenre);

    bUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);
    bView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bUpdate:
            boolean works = true;
            try {
                String mov = movie.getText().toString();
                String dir = director.getText().toString();
                String act = actors.getText().toString();
                String gen = genre.getText().toString();

                SeenIt entry = new SeenIt(MainActivity.this);
                entry.open();
                entry.createEntry(mov, dir, act, gen);
                entry.close();

            }catch(Exception e) {
                works = false;
                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("@+id/Works");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }finally {
                if(works) {

                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("@+id/dWorks");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("@+id/tvWorks");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }
            }

            break;

        case R.id.bView:
            Intent i = new Intent("com.example.seenit.SQLView");
            startActivity(i);

            break;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Use `findViewById(Your_Button_ID)` to initialize `bUpdate` and `bView` before setting `OnClickListeners` on them.

Comment: what is line:28 in main activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting listeners for buttons that doesn't exist yet, that's why you're getting a NullerPointerException. You have to put this code before the listeners, just like you did with the EditText.

```
bUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LayoutNameOfTheButton)
bView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LayoutNameOfTheButton)
```

Obviously you have to change the "LayoutNameOfTheButton" to the name of the element in your layout.